# create view by ranking user with points

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using this query and getting error  `#1351 - View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter`

```
CREATE VIEW v AS
SELECT  name,points,sno ,@rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
FROM  `users`,(Select @rownum := 0)
GROUP BY   name,sno
ORDER BY CAST(points AS UNSIGNED) DESC;
```

How do I create view with this? I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why are you using `select *` with `group by `sno`?

Comment: Hello Sir.I have updated the code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that `SNO` is actually unique in the `users` table, you can do this in a view without variables.  I'm not saying that you want to, but you can:

```
CREATE VIEW v AS
    SELECT  name,
            (select count(*)
             from users u2
             where u2.points > u.points or
                   u2.points = u.points and u2.sno <= u.sno
            ) as rank
    FROM  `users` u;
```

Comment: Awesome Sir .I had another query I am asking in next q .What if 5 users have same points then their rank should be same.But will next user skip ranks  or will have next rank?

Comment: @jason . . . As with your original query, if five users have the same points, they will each have their own rank.  If you have a different problem, then ask another question with that information.

Comment: Hello Sir Please have a look at this Q.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673843/get-latest-entry-even-if-2-records-have-same-timestamp  .Thank you Again Sir.

Answer (score 0):

As documented under [`CREATE VIEW` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-view.html):

> - The [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html) statement cannot refer to system or user variables.