# get latest entry even if 2 records have same timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the code below to retrieve the latest data w.r.t all users .But if the user had points added at the same time stamp then I would like to get the last entry not both like in the example below.How do I  make sure that I get latest entry even if 2 records have same timestamp.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/374db/1

I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists tblA
(
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
sender varchar(255),
receiver varchar(255),
 msg varchar(255),
 date timestamp,
  points varchar(255),
  refno varchar(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE if not exists tblB
(
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
sno varchar(255),
name varchar(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE if not exists tblC
(
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
data varchar(255),
  refno varchar(255),
  extrarefno varchar(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


INSERT INTO tblA (sender, receiver,msg,date,points,refno ) VALUES
('1', '2', 'buzz ...','2011-08-21 14:11:09','10','001'),
('1', '2', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:12:19','20','002'),
('4', '2', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:13:19','30','003'),
('1', '3', 'buzz ...','2011-08-21 14:11:09','10','004'),
('1', '3', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:12:19','20','005'),
('1', '4', 'buzz ...','2011-08-21 14:11:09','10','006'),
('1', '4', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:12:19','20','007'),
('3', '4', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:13:19','20','008'),
('2', '4', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:13:19','20','009');



INSERT INTO tblB (sno, name ) VALUES
('1', 'Aa'),
('2', 'Bb'),
('3', 'Cc'),
('4', 'Dd'),
('5', 'Ee'),
('6', 'Ff'),
('7', 'Gg'),
('8', 'Hh');


INSERT INTO tblC (data,refno,extrarefno ) VALUES
('data1', '001', '101'),
('data2', '002', '102'),
('data3', '003', '103'),
('data4', '004', '101'),
('data5', '005', '102'),
('data6', '006', '103'),
('data7', '007', '101'),
('data8', '008', '101'),
('data9', '009', '101');
```

///
query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (

  SELECT tblB.*, MAX(tblA.date) AS date
  FROM tblB
  JOIN tblA ON tblB.sno = tblA.receiver
  GROUP BY tblB.sno

) AS subset
JOIN tblA ON subset.sno = tblA.receiver 
            AND subset.date = tblA.date JOIN tblC ON tblA.refno=tblC.refno
```

Comment: Do you tried order by date desc, id desc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key idea is to use the `id` column instead of the `date` column.  It is auto-incremented, so the biggest id should be more recent.

However, your query has another problem which is the join to `tblB` in the subquery.  Arbitrary ("indeterminate") values from `tblB` would be returned in the outer query.  Instead, just aggregate on `tblA` and move the `join` to `tblB` to the outer level:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT tblA.receiver, MAX(tblA.id) AS id
      FROM tblA
      GROUP BY  tblA.receiver
    ) subset JOIN
    tblA
    ON subset.receiver = tblA.receiver AND subset.id = tblA.id JOIN
    tblB
    on tblA.receiver = tblB.sno join
    tblC
    ON tblA.refno=tblC.refno ;
```

Comment: This Solution Works Great.Thanks Once again Sir.

Comment: Hello Sir How can I rank users from the above query.I would like to make a view of it eventually.I created a view but I dont have rank column along with rankings .PLease Sir look into this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689226/rank-users-based-on-points/21689308?noredirect=1#21689308

Comment: Hello Sir I am struggling to get this to work .I am missing something.Please have a look.It would be of great help .Thanks .  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715642/rank-users-by-max-id-and-points

Answer (score 0):

Order by the date AND the id. The id is set to auto increment, if the date is the same, you can assume the higher id was created after.

```
ORDER BY date, id
```