# rank users based on points

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I rank the users below based on points .I really appreciate any help.
Thanks in Advance .

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/374db/11

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists tblA
(
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
sender varchar(255),
receiver varchar(255),
 msg varchar(255),
 date timestamp,
  points varchar(255),
  refno varchar(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE if not exists tblB
(
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
sno varchar(255),
name varchar(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE if not exists tblC
(
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
data varchar(255),
  refno varchar(255),
  extrarefno varchar(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


INSERT INTO tblA (sender, receiver,msg,date,points,refno ) VALUES
('1', '2', 'buzz ...','2011-08-21 14:11:09','10','001'),
('1', '2', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:12:19','20','002'),
('4', '2', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:13:19','30','003'),
('1', '3', 'buzz ...','2011-08-21 14:11:09','10','004'),
('1', '3', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:12:19','20','005'),
('1', '4', 'buzz ...','2011-08-21 14:11:09','10','006'),
('1', '4', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:12:19','20','007'),
('3', '4', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:13:19','20','008'),
('2', '4', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:13:19','20','009');



INSERT INTO tblB (sno, name ) VALUES
('1', 'Aa'),
('2', 'Bb'),
('3', 'Cc'),
('4', 'Dd'),
('5', 'Ee'),
('6', 'Ff'),
('7', 'Gg'),
('8', 'Hh');


INSERT INTO tblC (data,refno,extrarefno ) VALUES
('data1', '001', '101'),
('data2', '002', '102'),
('data3', '003', '103'),
('data4', '004', '101'),
('data5', '005', '102'),
('data6', '006', '103'),
('data7', '007', '101'),
('data8', '008', '101'),
('data9', '009', '101');
```

sql

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT tblA.receiver, MAX(tblA.id) AS id
      FROM tblA
      GROUP BY  tblA.receiver
    ) subset JOIN
    tblA
    ON subset.receiver = tblA.receiver AND subset.id = tblA.id JOIN
    tblB
    on tblA.receiver = tblB.sno join
    tblC
    ON tblA.refno=tblC.refno ;
```

Comment: Can you better explain your schema and data?  Your super-generic table names don't give us much insight into what your query really does and why it may be wrong.  What result do you get from your query now vs. what result are you looking for?

Comment: why column is the users?

Comment: Is the rank based on sum of points per tblA entry or sender?  Take a look at dense rank() over (order by points).  That might be what you are after.

Comment: ranking based on tblA points.the highest in this case 30 will be 1 the 20 -->2 then 20--> 3 .Coincidentally its in the same format but I dont know if its ranking.

Comment: @MikeBrant Something on the lines of this query `CREATE VIEW v AS
    SELECT  name,
            (select count(*)
             from users u2
             where u2.points > u.points or
                   u2.points = u.points and u2.sno <= u.sno
            ) as rank
    FROM  `users` u;`

Comment: basically having count and rank column ordered by points of tblA.

Comment: The view you are describing will give everyone the same rank.  Are you describing what you want accurately, or am I missing something.

Comment: Unfortunately, doing this in a view in MySQL is rather inefficient because you cannot use subqueries in the `from` clause and cannot use variables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for looking into it Sir.I have made 2 views the subquery is the 1st view and main query the 2nd view.But I would like to get count(*)--> ranking for the same .I tried it and it for some reason did not work .basically `create view v as SELECT tblA.receiver, MAX(tblA.id) AS id
      FROM tblA
      GROUP BY  tblA.receiver
    ) subset JOIN` and `create view  v2 as select * from v subset JOIN
    tblA
    ON subset.receiver = tblA.receiver AND subset.id = tblA.id JOIN
    tblB
    on tblA.receiver = tblB.sno join
    tblC
    ON tblA.refno=tblC.refno ;` Now how do I rank ?

Comment: @Jason . . . You have to do the rank with a correlated subquery in the `from` clause.  If you have any amount of data (thousands of rows), this could be quite inefficient.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I stuck and few steps .I would mention step by step to resolve the Query above .Firstly, `SELECT tblA.receiver, MAX(tblA.id) AS id,@rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
      FROM (SELECT @rownum := 0) t,tblA
      GROUP BY  tblA.receiver ORDER BY tblA.points DESC` works but `CREATE VIEW v AS SELECT tblA.receiver, MAX(tblA.id) AS id,@rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
      FROM (SELECT @rownum := 0) t,tblA
      GROUP BY  tblA.receiver ORDER BY tblA.points DESC`   does not work.How do I fix that ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Please Sir guide me through.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can order the results of a query using ORDER BY.  So, you can rank the rows in tblA as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblA
ORDER BY points
```

However, I notice you are using varchar for the points column.  If this is to hold a numerical value you probably want int or float.

Comment: can use `ORDER BY CAST(points AS UNSIGNED) DESC` but I am looking to make a view of this so I want query something like this `CREATE VIEW v AS
    SELECT  name,
            (select count(*)
             from users u2
             where u2.points > u.points or
                   u2.points = u.points and u2.sno <= u.sno
            ) as rank
    FROM  `users` u;`  though the query next would work I cannot convert it into view :`CREATE VIEW v AS
SELECT  name,points,sno ,@rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
FROM  users,(Select @rownum := 0)
GROUP BY   name,sno
ORDER BY CAST(points AS UNSIGNED) DESC;`