# rank users by max id and points but (rankings are wrong)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get highest points row along with ranks and select query without rownum=rownum+1 .I have tried the query below but I am missing something also link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd7897/7 .

I am looking for answer like for each receiver the last entry which would also be highest points entry rankwise:  I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

Something like this:

('2', '4', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:13:19','40','009')---rank1

('4', '2', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:13:19','30','003')----rank2

('1', '3', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:12:19','20','005')---- rank3

query so far:

```
    SELECT * ,
            (select count(*)
             from  tblA u2
             where u2.points > u.points or
                   u2.points = u.points and u2.id <= u.id
            ) as rank
FROM (SELECT u.receiver, MAX(u.id) AS id
      FROM tblA u
      GROUP BY  u.receiver
    ) subset JOIN
    tblA u
    ON subset.receiver = u.receiver AND subset.id = u.id order by rank;
```

tables:

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists tblA
(
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
sender varchar(255),
receiver varchar(255),
 msg varchar(255),
 date timestamp,
  points int(255),
  refno varchar(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE if not exists tblB
(
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
sno varchar(255),
name varchar(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE if not exists tblC
(
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
data varchar(255),
  refno varchar(255),
  extrarefno varchar(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


INSERT INTO tblA (sender, receiver,msg,date,points,refno ) VALUES
('1', '2', 'buzz ...','2011-08-21 14:11:09','10','001'),
('1', '2', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:12:19','20','002'),
('4', '2', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:13:19','30','003'),
('1', '3', 'buzz ...','2011-08-21 14:11:09','10','004'),
('1', '3', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:12:19','20','005'),
('1', '4', 'buzz ...','2011-08-21 14:11:09','10','006'),
('1', '4', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:12:19','20','007'),
('3', '4', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:13:19','30','008'),
('2', '4', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:13:19','40','009');



INSERT INTO tblB (sno, name ) VALUES
('1', 'Aa'),
('2', 'Bb'),
('3', 'Cc'),
('4', 'Dd'),
('5', 'Ee'),
('6', 'Ff'),
('7', 'Gg'),
('8', 'Hh');


INSERT INTO tblC (data,refno,extrarefno ) VALUES
('data1', '001', '101'),
('data2', '002', '102'),
('data3', '003', '103'),
('data4', '004', '101'),
('data5', '005', '102'),
('data6', '006', '103'),
('data7', '007', '101'),
('data8', '008', '101'),
('data9', '009', '101');
```

Comment: +1 for the data example, fiddle, all needed details :)

Comment: @JorgeCampos Thanks but struggling for the exact output ,The part of the subquery works but not the entire query.

Comment: I am a little confused. Why do you need tblB and tblC?

Comment: @Leo I dont need that for the above query.Those were additional tables but not w.r.t this example.BTW the query is working but the ranking are wrong.check it out http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd7897/7

Comment: the third rank isn't "('3', '4', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:13:19','30','008'),"?

Comment: oh, I see, the rank is by the receiver, right? (4 is already the first)

Comment: @Leo Yup exactly .Check out the latest sqlfiddle its working but ranks are 1,2,5 It should be 1,2,3 .And thats because the number of rows are less else the rank gets even worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `count(*)` in the subquery.  Change it to `count(distinct receiver)`:

```
SELECT * ,
       (select count(distinct receiver)
        from  tblA u2
        where u2.points > u.points or
              u2.points = u.points and u2.id <= u.id
       ) as rank
FROM (SELECT u.receiver, MAX(u.id) AS id
      FROM tblA u
      GROUP BY  u.receiver
    ) subset JOIN
    tblA u
    ON subset.receiver = u.receiver AND subset.id = u.id
order by rank;
```

EDIT:

To create this as a MySQL view, you have to get right of the aggregation in the `from` clause:

```
SELECT * ,
       (select count(distinct receiver)
        from  tblA u2
        where u2.points > u.points or
              u2.points = u.points and u2.id <= u.id
       ) as rank
FROM tblA u
WHERE u.id = (select max(u2.id) from tblA u2 where u2.receiver = u.receiver)
order by rank;
```

Comment: Sir I tried to add `create view unique_users_ranks as` before the above statement and I get `1349 - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause` I have tried everything but still I am stuck at the view part .How can I convert the above query to a view.Thats my end goal.Please help.

Comment: I was implementing all the views and queries you suggested and its working Sir .You are the BEST.Thanks again Sir will keep posting questions to you when I am stuck.Thanks again Sir for all the Help.I really appreciate it Sir.

Answer (score 1):

how about that?

```
SELECT a.*
FROM   tbla a,
       (SELECT receiver,
               Max(points) AS m
        FROM   tbla
        GROUP  BY receiver) AS b
WHERE  a.receiver = b.receiver
       AND a.points = b.m
ORDER  BY m DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that correlated sub-query of MySQL has poor performance. I think following query returns as same as result compared to yours and fast.

```
SELECT x.*, @ord := @ord + 1 AS rank
FROM (
    SELECT u.*
    FROM(SELECT u.receiver, MAX(u.id) AS id
          FROM tblA u
          GROUP BY  u.receiver
    ) subset INNER JOIN tblA u ON subset.receiver = u.receiver AND subset.id = u.id,
    (SELECT @ord := 0) init
    ORDER BY points DESC
) x
ORDER BY rank;
+----+--------+----------+----------+---------------------+--------+-------+------+
| id | sender | receiver | msg      | date                | points | refno | rank |
+----+--------+----------+----------+---------------------+--------+-------+------+
|  9 | 2      | 4        | test ... | 2011-08-21 14:13:19 |     40 | 009   |    1 |
|  3 | 4      | 2        | test ... | 2011-08-21 14:13:19 |     30 | 003   |    2 |
|  5 | 1      | 3        | test ... | 2011-08-21 14:12:19 |     20 | 005   |    3 |
+----+--------+----------+----------+---------------------+--------+-------+------+
```

Comment: but I cannot create the above query in a VIEW.Can you convert the above to a  view,

Comment: @jason Sorry. I didn't know that you asked a query in a VIEW. According to MySQL Manaul(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-view.html) we can't use user variables in a VIEW.